# WCF REST Service Update Header

Tags: wcf, rest

Using RequestInterceptor one can extract the HTTP headers from request and do some processing on them. One can also update response. However is there a way to update and/or insert HTTP headers in the request itself so that the subsequent processors (e.g. interceptors, authorization managers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has a *lot* of extension points for doing things like this.  What you are probably after is a custom behavior which implements `IDispatchMessageInspector`.

Create a class which looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomBehavior : IDispatchMessageInspector, IEndpointBehavior
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        //here you can work with request.Headers.
        return null;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    //there are a bunch of other methods needed
    //but you can leave their implementations empty.
    //...
}
```

You can then add your custom behavior to the service endpoint programatically before you open the service:

```
host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new WcfService2.MyCustomBehavior());
```

Paolo Pialorsi has a [good tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) which deals with writing message inspectors.

Comment: Headers are readonly in the Message class. public abstract MessageHeaders Headers { get; }.

Comment: Yes, `Headers` is get-only, but you can still call `Headers.Add(...)` to modify the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://wcf.codeplex.com the new HTTP stack has a pipelining model that allows you to do all kinds of things like this.

Comment: I can't use that yet as it is in preview. I am using the older REST starter kit. The request headers are readonly.    public sealed class HttpRequestMessageProperty
    {
        ...
        public WebHeaderCollection Headers { get; }
        ...
    }

Comment: @amit_g  The license on the REST starter kit basically prevents you from using it once MS releases the real version. For the server side stuff, the real version is in .Net 4 so the license is no longer valid.